# How to find the current position of an anchored element in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

To better explain this, I have a test site to where you can see my problem: http://andraecruz.com/_dev/1/index.html

In  here, I have 2 pages created. The navigation are setup in a form of anchor link tags so when I click on item 1 it jumps on the second page with the ID of #itemOne. This is working fine as it locates the proper ID on each slide. But when you click on another item on the navigation the proper order messes up. However, when you go directly to http://andraecruz.com/_dev/1/main.html, The navigation seems to work just fine.

I am new to jQuery and this might not be the best code solution for this one. Could anyone help me to solve this problem? Thanks.

To see my HTML markup, please click the link above and just view source on the page to see my code for both pages(index.html and main.html).

Since my navigation in an anchor tag, it looks the ID that matches on my second page which is my slide. And when you click the navigation again, it wont work at all. jQuery doesn't know that it slides on whatever ID it matches since the click was from the first page.

Here is my js code below:
$(function(){

```
$('.item1').click(function(){
    $('#itemOne').animate({left:'0'});
    $('#itemTwo').animate({left:'1000px'});
    $('#itemThree').animate({left:'2000px'});
    $('#itemFour').animate({left:'3000px'});
})
$('.item2').click(function(){
    $('#itemOne').animate({left:'-1000px'});
    $('#itemTwo').animate({left:'0'});
    $('#itemThree').animate({left:'1000px'});
    $('#itemFour').animate({left:'2000px'});
})
$('.item3').click(function(){
    $('#itemOne').animate({left:'-2000px'});
    $('#itemTwo').animate({left:'-1000px'});
    $('#itemThree').animate({left:'0'});
    $('#itemFour').animate({left:'1000px'});
})
$('.item4').click(function(){
    $('#itemOne').animate({left:'-3000px'});
    $('#itemTwo').animate({left:'-2000px'});
    $('#itemThree').animate({left:'-1000px'});
    $('#itemFour').animate({left:'0'});
})
```

});

Comment: It seems the browser gets in your way because as soon as it receives a hash in the URL, it brings the respective element into view, neglecting your `left` style entirely. This is the default behaviour. Can you try passing the item as a query string and then receive it in `main` and bring it into view yourself i.e. either by animating or jumping?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I could reproduce your problem the way you describe it, but nevertheless I will suggest here a solution that should solve your problem. First, give all of your slides a common class (e.g. `class="slide"`). Do the same for all your links (e.g. `class="item-link"`). Now, assign to each link of yours a `data-item` with values "One", "Two", "Three" and "Four" (e.g. `data-item="One"` for link "Item 1").

Now, the idea is to animate only the slide that corresponds to the link that was clicked, and hide all the others. So, your jQuery code would be something like (can't test from where I am, but should work despite any syntax errors):

```
$('.item-link').click(function(){
  var itemValue = $(this).data('item');
  $('.slide').hide();
  $('#item'+itemValue).animate({right:'1000px'});
})
```

This will probably render some undesired effects, like 'erasing' the current slide before sliding the new one and sliding always to the right, for example. If you can provide me a JS fiddle with your page's full code, I believe I can help you to make the necessary tweaks.

**EDIT**

OK, made some changes to my original answer and [got your fiddle working](http://jsfiddle.net/b4vw727f/2/) as I think you expected. Hope it helps. :)

Comment: Hi Lucas, I created a JSFiddle and you can view it here: https://jsfiddle.net/AndraeCruz/b4vw727f . The index.html is missing in there so I pasted my second page(The nav is working on the second page). Since this is based on anchor links. When you're coming from the first page it locates the ID

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the late answer. I'll try to modify your fiddle and update my answer with it.